# How to change the background color of Status bar color is displaying at bottom Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup to display Popup in Xamarin iOS. However I want the Status bar color is displaying at bottom of screen it's white to match the Popup's background color. I tried adding the `ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"` attribute. However it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

Popup.xaml

```
<popup:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns:ymmy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
            xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
            BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            .......>
    <popup:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation PositionIn="Bottom" PositionOut="Bottom" ScaleIn="1.2" ScaleOut="0.8" DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut" EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="False"/>
    </popup:PopupPage.Animation>
    <ymmy:PancakeView x:Name="BgStack" Padding="15" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#fff" BackgroundGradientStartPoint="0,0" BackgroundGradientEndPoint="0,1" CornerRadius="20,20,0,0">
        <StackLayout Padding="12,0" Margin="0">
            Grid Margin="0" Padding="0,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="Text....." Margin="0" TextColor="#393f57" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" FontSize="16"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <FontImageSource Color="#393f57" Size="20" FontFamily="Icon8Font" Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon8FontIcon.AngleRight}"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ymmy:PancakeView>
</popup:PopupPage>
```

[image]

Note that I only want the Status bar color is displaying at bottom of the Popup to be White.

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you

**Update**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

    UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
    UITabBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(51, 114, 221);            

    Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
    FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init();

    NativeMedia.Platform.Init(GetTopViewController);
    HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
    {
        TextColor = UIColor.Black,
        Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto Medium", 14)
    });

    Firebase.Core.App.Configure();


    LoadApplication(new App());
    DependencyService.Register<IAccountService, AccountServiceAuthPhone>();

    int red = 11;
    int green = 22;
    int blue = 33;
    bool canLoadUrl = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

    // get status bar and set color
    UIView statusBar;
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    {
        const int tag = 999;

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
        if (window is null) return null; //Error null

        statusBar = window.ViewWithTag(tag) ?? new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame)
        {
            Tag = tag
        };

        window.AddSubview(statusBar);
    }
    else
    {
        statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
    }
    if (!(statusBar is null))
    {
        statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(red, green, blue);
    }

    return canLoadUrl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use SafeArea hints that it should prevent you from overlapping the safe area... Not the other way. Did you try setting it to false?

Comment: You mean I should set UseSafeArea: ios:Page.UseSafeArea="false"?

Answer (score 0):

change the status bar color in  **FinishedLaunching**,

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
      {
            int red = 11;
            int green = 22;
            int blue = 33;
    
            // the usual Xamarin.Forms code
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
    
            bool canLoadUrl = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    
            // get status bar and set color
            UIView statusBar;
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                const int tag = 999; 
    
                var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
                if (window is null) return null;
    
                statusBar = window.ViewWithTag(tag) ?? new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame)
                {
                    Tag = tag
                };
    
                window.AddSubview(statusBar);
            }
            else
            {
                statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
            }
            if (!(statusBar is null))
            {
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(red, green, blue);
            }
    
            return canLoadUrl;
       }**
```

Comment: I updated it in AppDelegate.cs. However it doesn't work :( I'm testing on iOS 15.0

Comment: I have updated above, you can see it

Comment: try replace the UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0) with 15

Comment: I will try it and feedback here. Thank you

Comment: I dug deeper into the Rg.Plugins.Popup docs and I got it working. Thank you

Comment: you can post your own answer